# App crashing when adding completion to the observer

Tags: swift, swift3, swift4

I'm trying to add a block to the notification observer, but the app is getting crashed when moving foreground and background. If I'm adding method to observer its working fine, only in case of block its getting crashed. Here is my code which I'm trying for the same.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(foregroundEntered(closure:)), name: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    
    @objc func foregroundEntered(closure: () -> Void) {
        /// do some stuff
    }
        
    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please post crash log

Comment: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x8) I understand some memory issue. But not able to figure it out. Thread 1 Queue : com.apple.main-thread (serial)

Comment: try `@objc func foregroundEntered(closure: NSNotification) {`  ??

Comment: @ Sh_Khan Thanks for helping me. That will work, but I have a requirement to add a block.  I'm calling the same method in multiple places. So I need to add a block there instead of method. I'm just trying with block.

Comment: selector can't work with block you need to use the completion callback variety of that observer

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
@objc func foregroundEntered(closure: () -> Void) {
```

With

```
@objc func foregroundEntered(_ notif: NSNotification) {
```

And change

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(foregroundEntered), name: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)
```